# Prove by induction $|u - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |u^{n} - y^{n}| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, induction, epsilon-delta

Specifically, show that $\forall u \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \quad |u - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |u^{n} - y^{n}| < \epsilon$

I am trying to see if I am understanding this correctly. I have written out a proof in as much detail as I think is necessary.  I feel shaky when it comes to using the $P(n)$ case to help prove $P(n+1)$.

Proof.

Base case n=1 is trivial.  We will only proceed with the inductive step n+1.

For convenience suppose $|u| > |y|$.  We expand $P(n+1)$
\begin{align*}
|u^{n+1} - y^{n+1}| & = |(u-y)(u^{n} + u^{n-1}y + ... + y^{n})| \\
& \leq |u-y|(|u^{n}| + |u^{n-1}y| + ... + |y^{n}|) \\
& \leq |u-y| \cdot (n+1) \cdot \max(\{|u|,|y|\})^{n} \\
& < \delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n}
\end{align*}

For $P(n)$ the statement holds true so lets first expand on this case to be able to proceed with case $P(n+1)$.
\begin{align*}
|u^{n} - y^{n}| & = |(u-y)(u^{n-1} + u^{n-2}y + ... + y^{n-1})| \\
& \leq |u-y|(|u^{n-1}| + |u^{n-2}y| + ... + |y^{n-1}|) \\
& \leq |u-y| \cdot n \cdot \max(\{|u|,|y|\})^{n-1} \\
& < \delta \cdot n \cdot |u|^{n-1} \\
& < \delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Our choice of delta will depend on the value of $|u|$ and $\epsilon$.  If $|u| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |u|^{n} \leq 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (it does not matter if it is $n-1$ or $n$), such that
\begin{align*}
\delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n} \leq \delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot 1
\end{align*}

and so we pick $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{n+1}$.  If $|u| > 1 \Rightarrow |u|^{n} > |u|^{n-1}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n-1} < \delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n}
\end{align*}

and so we pick $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{(n+1) \cdot |u|^{n}}$.

In any of the two cases we can choose a delta such that.
\begin{align*}
|u - y| < \delta \Rightarrow |u^{n} - y^{n}| < \delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n} = \epsilon
\end{align*}

a statement that holds true since $P(n)$ holds true.

Having found the necessary delta, we return to $P(n+1)$.  We choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{n+1}$ if $|u| \leq 1$ or $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{(n+1) \cdot |u|^{n}}$ if $|u| > 1$ such that the following is holds true
\begin{align*}
|u^{n+1} - y^{n+1}| & < \delta \cdot (n+1) \cdot |u|^{n} = \epsilon \\
|u^{n+1} - y^{n+1}| & < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Any feedback is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Induction scarcely seems necessary. Your first line of inequalities proves the claim. With mere continuity, you can treat one of the variables as "fixed" and use it to help find your $\delta$.

Comment: Induction is involved at some level.  The choice of $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon, u$ and $n$, as factoring $u^n - y^n$ would suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to use the truth of $P(n) $ to establish the truth of $P(n+1)$. Rather you establish the truth of both $P(n) $ and $P(n+1)$ independently using same approach.

You can however use induction in following manner. It is obvious that $P(1)$ is true. Let's assume the truth of $P(n) $. Thus given any $\epsilon>0$ and $u\in\mathbb{R} $ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|u-y|<\delta$ then $|u^n-y^n|<\epsilon $.

Now consider the expression $$|u^{n+1}-y^{n+1}|\leq |u^{n+1}-u^ny|+|u^ny-y^{n+1}|\\\leq |u^n||u-y|+|y||u^n-y^n|$$ If $|u-y|<1$ then $|y|<|u|+1$ and hence by above inequality we have $$|u^{n+1}-y^{n+1}|\leq (|u^n|+1)|u-y|+(|u|+1)|u^n-y^n|$$ Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then by truth of $P(n) $ there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that if $|u-y|<\delta_1$ then $|u^n-y^n|<\epsilon/(2(|u|+1))$. Let $$\delta=\min\left(1,\delta_1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(|u^n|+1)}\right)$$ then for $|u-y|<\delta$ we have $$|u^{n+1}-y^{n+1}|<(|u^n|+1)\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2(|u^n|+1)}+(|u|+1)\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2(|u|+1)}=\epsilon$$ and this establishes the truth of $P(n+1)$.

Comment: Ah this is great! I was caught up with the inequality $|u^{n+1} - y^{n+1}| = |(u-y)(u^{n} + u^{n-1}y + ... + y^{n})|$ that I didn't think to factor out $|u^{n} - y^{n}| $ from $|u^{n+1} - y^{n+1}| $ and hence use the truth of $P(n)$.  Thanks!

Comment: @minorthreat: Just in case you didn't notice those $+1$ in $|u|+1$ were to avoid division by zero in case $u=0$.